# Could anyone share me access to a TFS server?

Tags: tfs, share

I just want to Test my Team Explorer, but due to some bad limits, I can not install my own TFS server.
A Read Only Authority to a sample project with some workitems will be OK,
And I will not visit it frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the free `Team Foundation Service`? It can be found [here](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/).

You are given your own TFS collection for free.  There is a maximum of 5 users

Comment: Thanks, but I did not find any url in your link,like the following:"http://servername:8080/ where is it?

Comment: You're not following. Team Foundation Service is a free service from Microsoft.  They give you a free TFS Server.  You need to sign up and then you can access it.  I don't think you'll find anyone willing to give you access to their own private TFS Server!!!

Comment: Thanks! I have created such site: https://leiyang.visualstudio.com/ project name is LeiYangTestTFS. But I can not access it using Team Explorer. It just says cannot reach, not problems of Authority. Can you visit it?